# how can i call nginx server using internal IP in gcp

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have an Nginx server configured with no external access means there is no external IP address associated (this Nginx server is deployed in a particular VPC)

so now I want to access this Nginx server so for that I created a demo VM in the same network where the Nginx server is deployed so inside this VM I tried.

```
curl $Nginx-internal-ip
```

but it says curl: (7) Failed to connect to ${nginx-internal-ip} port 80: Connection refused

Comment: You need to check firewall rules, your application port and you need to make sure that your are making request from inside of VPC

Comment: @Aadeshkale thanks for responding i am making request from my vpc and in firewall i allowed 80 port for all instance in the network. but still not ablw to access in internally ( this is when i created vm without external IP but when i create VM with external IP i am able to make request but i do not want external ip )